# Extracting complex names with stringr str_extract R: dealing with "DE", "VAN"

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to deal with complex names and surnames from a dataframe.

```
list <- c("DUPONT J", "DUPONT DE JEAN, V", "JEAN V Y","DE DUPONT Z V","DUPONT VAN RIVIERE Z")
```

As a result I would like just [COMPLETE NAME] [BLANK] [SURNAME 1st LETTER]:

```
list2 <- c('DUPONT J', 'DUPONT DE JEAN V',"JEAN V","DE DUPONT Z","DUPONT VAN RIVIERE Z")
```

I tried to use the str_extract function but I have issue with the "DE" or "VAN" in names to extract the whole names.

```
str_extract(temp1$value, "[A-Z]+\\s[A-Z]")
```

I think the right code would be kind of :
1) identify what is the first surname letter
2) take everything before the first surname letter.

Comment: I dont really get your logic. Why do you remove the `Y` from `Jean V Y` but remove nothing from `Dupont Van Riviere Z` ?

Comment: I don't know why but in my data base, sometime they put one first letter of the surname and sometime two. "DUPONT VAN RIVIERE" is the complete lastname and "Z" the first letter of the surname. In "Jean V Y", "Jean" is the lastname and V the first letter of the surname

Comment: Aren't "Last name" and "Surname" the same thing? Or do you mean "First/Given Name" when you say "Surname"

Answer (score 0):

Any easier approach might be to look for two repeating single characters at the end of the string and drop the second character

```
gsub("(\\s\\w)\\s\\w$", "\\1", list)
```

The output also removed the comma which would be done with a separate command

```
gsub(",", "", gsub("(\\s\\w)\\s\\w$", "\\1", list))

[1] "DUPONT J" "DUPONT DE JEAN V" "JEAN V" "DE DUPONT Z" "DUPONT VAN RIVIERE Z"
```